# Position of elements inside layout change because screen size

Tags: android, android-layout, layout, android-linearlayout, android-relativelayout

I have this layout and when I run the application on the first emulator the layout show all of the element as i want. But when I launch it on the Second emulator which has smaller screen the elements of the layout are getting missed and not arranged.

**My Question:** How to make the layout independent for all the Devices because not all the devices have the same screen size. In other words, I want the position of elements to stay static even the screen size of the emulator is changed.

**This is the First Emulator Screenshot:**

[image]

**This is the Second Emulator Screenshot:**

[image]

**And this is the Layout Code:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout

    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/light_primary_color"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/feed_item_margin"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/feed_item_margin"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/feed_item_margin"
        android:background="@drawable/bg_parent_rounded_corner"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/feed_item_padding_top_bottom"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/feed_item_padding_top_bottom" >


        <com.android.volley.toolbox.NetworkImageView
            android:id="@+id/summary_image_View"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:paddingRight="5dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            />

        <LinearLayout
         android:weightSum="3"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/feed_item_padding_left_right"
            android:paddingRight="@dimen/feed_item_padding_left_right" >


            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:paddingLeft="@dimen/feed_item_profile_info_padd" >
                <com.android.volley.toolbox.NetworkImageView
                    android:id="@+id/summary_first_team_logo"
                    android:layout_width="60dp"
                    android:layout_height="60dp"
                    android:scaleType="fitCenter" />
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/summary_first_team"
                    android:layout_marginTop="20sp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="20sp"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textColor="@color/primary_dark_color"
                    android:textSize="20sp"
                    android:text="Test"

                    />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:paddingLeft="@dimen/feed_item_profile_info_padd" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/summary_match_date"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:background="@color/light_primary_color"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:textColor="@color/primary_text"
                    android:textSize="20sp"
                    android:text="Test"

                    />

                <TextView
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:id="@+id/summary_match_result"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:background="@color/light_primary_color"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textColor="@color/primary_text"
                    android:textSize="20sp"
                    android:text="Test"

                    />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10sp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:paddingLeft="20sp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                >

                <TextView

                    android:id="@+id/summary_second_team"
                    android:layout_marginTop="20sp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10sp"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textColor="@color/primary_dark_color"
                    android:textSize="20sp"
                    android:text="Test"

                    />

                <com.android.volley.toolbox.NetworkImageView
                    android:id="@+id/summary_second_team_logo"
                    android:layout_width="60dp"
                    android:layout_height="60dp"
                    android:scaleType="fitCenter" />
            </LinearLayout>


        </LinearLayout>


    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of implementing tabs in the way you have above, I would take a look at the [`TabLayout`](http://developer.android.com/intl/zh-cn/reference/android/support/design/widget/TabLayout.html) widget.

It allows you to make tabs more easily, and it is generally better practice to do it using a `TabLayout` rather than lots of `LinearLayout`s).

Using a `TabLayout` also allows you to set the mode (using [`setTabMode(int)`](http://developer.android.com/intl/zh-cn/reference/android/support/design/widget/TabLayout.html#setTabMode(int))), so you can make your tabs scrollable so that they fit better on smaller screen sizes.

Comment: Sir, thanks for replying. But I want the Linear layout to fit in the screen not only the Tabs. 
Also, I think i can't  use TabLayout instead of LinearLayout because I have to initialize them from the MainActivity. I just want the position of the elements in the Layout stay static even the device screen is small or large.

Comment: @DodoDodo Having widgets remain in a static position for different screen sizes and densities is discouraged. Your layouts should be responsive and adapt to the device's screen (not as you have shown in the emulator, but in a cleaner, nicer, well-designed way). It would be difficult to make all the views on the screen stay in the same position on all screen sizes without text, for example, being continued on a new line.

Answer (score 0):

As you are using  `android:weightSum` in your linear layout,I would suggest that use `android:weightSum` in the sub linear Layout as you are assigning "60dp" inside for image view,assign some weight to it.